# Use of "Having said that" with "However"?

Tags: grammar

Is it ok to use "However" with "Having said that" in the same sentence? I think their meaning is the same and it causes duplication. But I have found this sentence in a book.

For example:

**Nuclear power has its problems. However, having said that, many people believe it is the energy source of the future.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct: using both is a bit redundant since they really have the same meaning. It's not wrong though. It comes down to a stylistic preference. Some writers like to be wordy. Others view this as poor or sloppy style and try to be as concise as possible. I'm in the latter category (I don't always succeed, but that is my goal). I also find "having said that" an awkward choice of words in *written* material, since of course no one actually "said" anything!